# How can I invoke an Excel Macro in Excel from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, excel, com, vba

I would like to invoke an Excel Macro or an VBA function in Excel from Matlab. How should achieve this? I suppose I should create a handle with

```
filename = './sampleWorkbook';
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
```

Then how should I proceed to invoke an VBA funciton in that Excel workbook filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.  Make a call to `Application.Run("macroname")` and you should be fine.  Make sure `macroname` is in a VBA `Module` in your Excel Workbook and has `Public` scope.

```
filename = './sampleWorkbook';
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
Excel.Application.Run("macroname");
```

Here is a link to MSDN documentation for `Application.Run` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Joehanna. I found the Excel.Application.Run command as well. The format Excel.Application.Run "macroname"; does not work though in Matlab though. It has to be Excel.Application.Run('macroname');

Comment: Great!  I will update my answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, coming very close to what joehanna has, but with the Run command in the correct Matlab format and closing the workbook previously opened and releasing the activeX server.

```
filename = 'C:\Book1.xlsm';
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
%excel.Visible = 1;
excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
retval = excel.Run('trial');
excel.Workbooks(1).Close
excel.Quit
excel.release
```